# Manipulating scikit-image regionprops results

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am completely new to Python and struggle a bit with the data handling. I have been using Matlab for most of my data analysis so far.

I am analyzing an image with skimage.measure.regionprops which outputs a list of properties. Now, I process the image in subregions and want to change items in this list.

Specifically, I cut one region in two while working on a subimage. Now I want include my updated regions into the list. Since I am working on a subregion, the centroid property does not give me the coordinates in the full image. So, I would like to add the offset values to correct for this.

**But**, I cannot edit the regionprops output list. I first tried to edit the centroid property, but it's a tuple and these are apparently unchangeable. Then, I tried deleting the centroid field and replace it with my new values, but apparently I also cannot change the property list at all.

Is there any way I can manipulate the regionprops result list?

I am working on a workaround, but I was wondering if this is at all possible...

Comment: Can you cast the tuple to a list using the `list()` function and then modify in place? An alternative would be to create a class that inherits from the regionprops object and give it another attribute containing the information required to translate the information to the original image.

Comment: I tried that, but I need to insert the manipulated list back into the original result list, because I process the full regionprops list in the next step

Comment: I have scikit-image v 0.10.1 I presume you're on a different version?

Answer (score -1):

```
from skimage.measure import regionprops
import numpy as np

arr = np.zeros((10, 10))

arr[[1, 4, 9], [1, 4, 9]] = 1
arr[[4, 7, 8], [2, 4, 6]] = 2
```

This creates an array that looks like this:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])


list_from_regprops = regionprops(arr.astype(int))
```

This generates your list of regions and you can access by indexing the list and extracting the value you want to alter, then just overwrite using the same mechanism

```
#list_from_regprops = [r1, r2, r3]


old_centroid_x, old_centroid_y = list_from_regprops[0].centroid
new_centroid_x, new_centroid_y = old_centroid_x + 4, old_centroid_y - 4#for example
list_from_regprops[0].centroid = new_centroid_x, new_centroid_y
```

This should do what you need, just replace the 0 with whatever index you need to alter.

Comment: Can you specify the first line how to extract data from the regionprops list? So, you copy the data into a changeable list instead of manipulating the original one?

Comment: I just modified the output of regionprops in place - will edit.
As far as I can see, the only thing you can't modify in place is the centroid tuple. However, you can extract the individual values, modify and then overwrite the old tuple with a new one

Comment: yeah, but that doesn't work. I cannot overwrite the centroid in the list_from_regprops. I get an error: "AttributeError: can't set attribute"

Comment: I have scikit-image v 0.10.1 I presume you're on a different version?

Comment: It might be because centroid is derived from coords, I think that you should look at updating the coords attribute if you can, and then recalculate centroid which is just the mean of coords

Comment: I have v 0.14.0, sure I can calculate the centroid myself, but I still won't be able to write that into the original list. and what's the point of having the regionprops list with all the results when I need to start making a separate list calculating all features myself?

Comment: @Frieke It looks like you're trying to do something that regionprops wasn't designed for - the object you're dealing with is designed to be read-only, I suspect because it used to be writeable and that has lead to undesirable effects for some users. You could create a new class that inherits from _RegionProperties and add a __setattr__ method to it to allow you to modify in place. An alternative hack would be to store the index and new centroid as key:value pairs in a dictionary and check the dict when you want to do something with the centroid to make sure you use the right one

Comment: Too bad, that this doesn't seem to be possible. Thanks for your effort, Andrew. I am now working on the full picture with a mask that blacks out the rest of the image to use the dimensions of the original image. That works for me..

Comment: Yikes, 0.10 is a long time ago, @Andrew! @Frieke, sorry that regionprops doesn't quite do what you want anymore. Please consider raising an issue on github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image to add an `offset=` keyword argument to regionprops.